# DDR3 ECC 16gb 2rx4 PC3-14900r - Identification of the damaged chip by memory address

Tags: memory, ddr3, ecc

I got 4 16GB 2Rx4 PC3-14900R memory chips; [Samsung M393B2G70DB0-CMA](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393B2G70DB0-CMA/)

Out of 4 memory sticks, 1 OK, 2 report ECC errors (correctable - 1bit), 1 dead.

I would like to replace the damaged chips. There are 36 of memory chips on a memory stick and  I don't know which one is damaged. How do I identify the damaged chips?

This is the memtest86 error message.

> Memory Range Tested 0x200000000 - 240000000 (1024MB)
>
> 2021-09-04 19:19:28 - [ECC Error] Test: 5, (Rank,Bank,Row,Col):
> (N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A), ECC Corrected: Yes, Syndrome: N/A, Channel/Slot:
> 5/0

aditional sugestion I had found over internet says that is not easly possible without specialized eq
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/dimm-testing-is-there-any-solution.361390/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the memory modules do not route different addresses to different chips, so you can't determine which chip is broken based on address.

All the chips get the same address bus, and your module has 4 bits of data per chip, so to provide 72-bit data bus, 18 chips work on the same address at one given time, and given the datasheet, module has 36 chips in 2 ranks.

If you are able to determine which data pins do not work on an faulty address, then it will narrow it further down to 2 chips of two ranks.

If you know how the memory controller is set up, you might be able to determine which of the ranks has the broken chip.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to do it?  I know that there are some specialized testers for it but I have no access to any kind of that device. In theory I could calculate it having row/column info but unfortunately it is not reported.